# How to find the row of the cell that has the max value (or any other formula) in excel/sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a large data set that looks a bit like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 5 |
| 12 | 9 |

Basically, I'm trying to get the row number for the max value in each column.
So in this example, for col A, I would get 2, and for col B, I would get 2.

I've found the maxium value using the MAX function but can't seem to figure out finding the row of the number that is that max value.

I've tried VLOOKUP and MATCH but just can't work it out.

Thanks.

I am hoping to get a formula and ideally how to use it so I may apply it to my work.

Answer (score 1):

Use MATCH:

```
=MATCH(MAX(A:A),A:A,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For google-sheet use `BYCOL()` and `XMATCH()`.

```
 =BYCOL(A:B,LAMBDA(col,XMATCH(MAX(col),col)))
```

[image]